# Создание постера с помощью VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня есть рабочий скрипт который может публиковать текст и изображения в ВК. Но как опубликовать постер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) про это ничего не сказано.

Comment: Этот вопрос на английском языке - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504739/how-to-post-a-poster-to-vkontakte-social-network-wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В запросе надо добавить параметр `poster_bkg_id={номер_фона_для_постера}`. В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) этот параметр действительно не описан (спасибо автору https://github.com/VBIralo/vk-posters).

### Фоны (poster_bkg_id)

- Градиенты

  > 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- Иллюстрации

  > 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 31, 32
- Патерны Emoji

  > 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30